# Triggering a Sleep Wake-up Event using analog output from a triple axis accelerometer?

Tags: sleep, analog, mkr-gsm-1400

I am working on a project that uses a [Arduino MKR GSM 1400](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/mkr-gsm-1400) and a [ADXL335 Accelerometer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9269) . I am having trouble setting a interrupt wake up event on one of the GSM's interrupt-capable pin due to the analog nature of the ADXL335's output. The axis outputs typically range between ~1.4V-~2.2V with ~1.65V being the resting voltage level.

I have tried using a [NTE987](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/nte987/nte-electronics) op-amp to amplify the analog output enough to trigger a CHANGE on the interrupt pin I'm using. This resulted in the analog signal outputted by the ADXL335 boosting to a certain voltage level and not varying at all with any motion.

My current solution, which works very well but is not ideal for power consumption reasons, is using a smaller micro controller with less power draw's ADC to interpret the ADXL335's output and send digital wake-up signals to the GSM when certain thresholds are met. I would like to know if there's a better way to do this, as using an additional microcontroller to wake up the original microcontroller feels like a kludge.

Comment: What is the power draw of the opamp? That opamps shouldn't draw that much current.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the SAMD21. But some micro controllers have comparitors in them that can trigger an interrupt when the voltage gets above/below a certain value. I'm not sure what you are measuring with the accelerometer, but if the triggering motion isn't a short one, you could have the MCU sleep most of the time, and wake up, say, once a second to do a measurement.

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ultra+low+power+comparator&ia=web

Comment: You need to remove that 1.65V offset *before* amplifying it. The simplest way is to AC couple it with a capacitor.